# How do I get all select elements that do not have an option selected using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get all select elements that do not have an option selected using jQuery?

```
<select id="one">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="test"></option>
</select>

<select id="two">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option selected value="test"></option>
</select>
```

What would the jQuery selector be that would return just #one based on no selection?

Comment: A `<select>`'s default selection is the first option (if not `selected` atribute is present), so do you mean to get the `<select>` elements that have selected your first option (`""`)?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right, but "" would not have the selected attribute by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63588880/3499595 if your case is not similar to OP (default value is "")*

```
$('select option:selected[value=""]').parent()
```

- Selects all the `:selected` options of all the `select` elements
- Checks if the selected option has a value of `""`, which in your case means no option is actually selected.
- Returns the parent (which would be a `select`)

Comment: Doesn't that produce the opposite of what the asker requested? That gives all `select` elements that *do* have a selected option..

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of jQuery's [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) functions. See below:

```
// selector for all 'select' elements with any option below it
var all = $("select>option").parent(); // alternative $("select")

// selector for all 'select' element with a selected child
var selected = $("select>option[selected]").parent();

// the subtraction set "all - selected" achieved by `not`.
var unselected = all.not(selected);
```

Note that jQuery's `parent` takes care of removing duplicates from a set of parents of child elements.

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/szq6t6r2/).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer gives all `select` elements with a *selected* option whose value is empty(`""`), which does answer the question in regard to the OP's sample HTML, where options with empty values are given, but it doesn't really answer the title question.

There is a difference between selecting an option with an empty value, and not selecting any option at all.

To select all `select` elements with *no* option selected, use

```
 $('select').not(':has(option:selected)')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery library then try

```
$('select option').filter(function(i,d){return !d.hasAttribute("selected")});
```